# How would I remove the none as output in my python file

Tags: python, if-statement

I am making a simple program for just testing my knowledge and.
So this is what I have made right now. I have some code which is used for basic operations of math
plus minus divide and multiply the code works fine until someone divides with 0 for which i have an if statement which prints my desired output but with a none. I saw that doing !=-1 makes it go away but it works for strings when i tried before.

Tried to implement !=-1 didn't work looking to remove None as output

```
a = input("What would you like to do? ") 
num1 = input("Input value one ") 
num2 = input("Input value two ") 

def add(x,y): 
    return(int(x)+int(y)) 

def minus(x,y): 
    return(int(x)-int(y)) 

def multiply(x,y): 
    return(int(x)*int(y)) 

def divide(x,y): 
    if (int(num1)>=0 or int(num2)!=-1)>=0: 
        print("Number can not be equal zero") else: 
        return(int(x)//int(y)) 
    if a == "Addition": 
        print(add(num1,num2)) 
    elif a == "Minus": 
        print(minus(num1,num2)) 
    elif a == "Multiply": 
        print(multiply(num1,num2)) 
    elif a == "Division": 
        print(divide(num1,num2))
```

Comment: random guess..! print statement replace with return statement..

Comment: Consider that every operation ***`return`s*** something, just not the divide-by-zero case…

Answer (score 0):

```
def divide(x,y): 
    if (int(num1)>=0 or int(num2)!=-1)>=0: 
        print("Number can not be equal zero") else: 
        return(int(x)//int(y))
```

use raise exption may be what you want.

```
def divide(x,y): 
    if int(num1)>=0 or int(num2)!=-1: 
        raise ValueError("Number can not be equal zero")
    else: 
        return(int(x)//int(y))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = input("What would you like to do? ") 
num1 = input("Input value one ") 
num2 = input("Input value two ") 

def add(x,y): 
    return(int(x)+int(y)) 

def minus(x,y): 
    return(int(x)-int(y)) 

def multiply(x,y): 
    return(int(x)*int(y)) 

def divide(x,y): 
    if int(y) == 0: 
        pass
    else:
        return(int(x)//int(y)) 

if a == "Addition": 
    print(add(num1,num2)) 
elif a == "Minus": 
    print(minus(num1,num2)) 
elif a == "Multiply": 
    print(multiply(num1,num2)) 
elif a == "Division": 
    print(divide(num1,num2))
```